# What does Spring's @Cacheable do when placed on a method returning a list?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I've looked everywhere online for a simple answer to the above question, and just can't find it. I have a method like:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "objects")
public List<Object> get() { .. }
```

I'm using EhCache 2.10.0 with Spring Framework 4.2.1, and I can see the following output for this method:

```
Adding cacheable method 'get' with attribute: [CacheableOperation[public java.util.List com.example.DAO.get()] caches=[objects] | key='' ...
```

also (in later logging)

```
Computed cache key 'SimpleKey []' for operation ...
```

What is the @Cacheable annotation *supposed* to do in this situation? Place each object in the cache keyed by hashCode (as hinted at elsewhere)? Or just plonk the whole list as-is into the cache under some list-based hashCode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Spring Doc mentions this:

> Since caches are essentially key-value stores, each invocation of a
>   cached method needs to be translated into a suitable key for cache
>   access. Out of the box, the caching abstraction uses a simple
>   KeyGenerator based on the following algorithm:
>
> - > If no params are given, return `SimpleKey.EMPTY`
> - > If only one param is given, return that instance
> - > If more the one param is given, return a key computed from the hashes of all parameters.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache

When you annotate it with `@Cacheable(cacheNames = "objects")` you give it a cache name against which it can identify the cache. Since your method doesn't have any arguments, for the cacheName as "objects", it will have already cached the return object (`List<Object>` in this case). and every time the method is called, it will check the cache with the cacheName object and with the key value as '0'. If it already has a return object that was cached previous time, it will return the object.

**Updated**: with `SimpleKey.EMPTY` key for no params for Spring 4+

Comment: So it will return the entire list on the second invocation of the get() method?

Comment: Yes it would. As it has already a record that the method was executed the object is cached. Please note that your method has to be public as well to work.

Comment: Can individual objects in the list be cached under separate keys?

Comment: The "Result" of the method is actually cached. It means the cache is not against the object, it's against the method name and it's arguments(as highlighted by java docs) and the result of the method is cached along. It doesn't care about what type of object it is. It just caches the result `Object`

Comment: Spring 4.0+ returns SimpleKey.EMPTY [rather than 0](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html), hence the output from my application, but either way, very helpful.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to add each object to a separate cache by id in addition to caching the full list but don't see any way to do it in spring cache.